# <MasterEventCell 0x8975ae0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key EventDetails What is wrong here?

Tags: ios, iphone, runtime-error

I am coding this for my final project. I am struggling with finding the error in my code. It is a runtime error, since it compiles and opens the simulator, but displays this message after running:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key EventDetails.'

I know that when there is an error code like this, I have found responses like "inconsistent classes" or "not using the proper method". I am unsure where I went wrong, though. Everything in my MasterEventCell files seem to be consistent with what I am trying to do (have a custom label created and defined). Can anyone give me insight as to what is wrong?

MasterEventCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MasterEventCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventDetailsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventLocationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *eventDateLabel;


@end
```

MasterEventCell.m:

```
#import "MasterEventCell.h"

@implementation MasterEventCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)masterCell
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:masterCell];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

My project link is below.

*Link to project removed.*

Comment: Your nib/storyboard file has a link to a property that you've renamed or deleted.  Find it and delete it from interface builder.

Comment: I'm using storyboard. Should I be looking under the Attributes inspector for this renamed/deleted property?

Comment: Look in the MasterEventCell's connections inspector.

Comment: I can't post a photo because of my lack of reputation on this site, but under the connections inspector, I have no connections. Could this be the problem? Note: there IS a connection between each of the declarations of labels in MasterEventCell.h and the respective label in the Storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in your project....

Open your storyboard, expand the Final Master View Controller - Master Scene, click on the Master Event Cell - FinalCell element, show the connections inspector.

Look at the Outlets section and you'll see that three of the six have warning symbols beside them: dateTime, EventDetails, and location.  Those don't exist in your code; delete them.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this question: [this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key PerformRotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845905/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-performrotate?rq=1)

Your error message reports wanting to access a key called "EventDetails" - this doesn't show up in the code snippet you posted, but look for where this is - or was - in your code.  there is still a reference to  "EventDetails" in your storyboard, which may now be "eventDetails" (note case change at beginning of name)... or something else entirely.

Comment: I am certain you are right, as many above have said. Maybe I am not experienced with Storyboard yet, but I cannot seem to find exactly where in the storyboard I would be referencing "EventDetails". I have checked all of my controller and views, and cannot seem to find where I am going wrong

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you very much!